# Can I adjust item frequency?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

Is it possible to control the item frequency in smash battles? In all three previous games, the Item Switch had an appearance frequency control that would set how often items appear overall. In SSB4, this control appears to be gone. Is it still there, but harder to find, is it unlockable, or is it just gone?

Comment: Nintendo just confirmed that the Wii U version will allow you to adjust item frequency, unlike the 3DS version.

Comment: Seems like an easy enough feature to add, they probably did it to make the Wii U version appear superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no longer included in the game. (Sadly)

You can merely adjust the items and whether or not they fall.

Here are a few sources I found, and while none have concrete evidence, no evidence pointing towards an unlock or hidden feature has been found.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632937-super-smash-bros-for-nintendo-3ds/70215054

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632937-super-smash-bros-for-nintendo-3ds/70257251

http://smashboards.com/threads/change-item-frequency.371589/